# iPad and HTML5 video tag

Tags: html, ipad, nexus-7

Good afternoon,  I have searched through the stackoverflow pages and the web and can't seem to find an answer.  I have a site that uses the HTML5 video tag.  I use MP4 files as my video files.  I created a simple tag:

```
<video id="videoPlayer" width="958px" height="444px" src="video/test.mp4" controls>
  NOT Supported
</video>
```

When I open in a PC browser it works just fine and plays as I want it to.  When I open the file on my iPad or Nexus 7 this is what happens:

iPad: I get a play button with a line crossing it out.
Nexus 7: I get a play button.  When I press the play button nothing happens.

At first I thought it was something I did wrong so I went to W3Schools video tag portion on my iPad and the example video doesn't load there either.  I checked the iOS version and it is up to date at 5.1.1.  I'm at a loss on what to do.  Please help.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Update: I can now load the W3Schools examples on the iPad.  not sure why it didn't load before but I am still having the same issue with my site.

Comment: have you checked (using something like VLC) if the videos will play on the devices in question? Also I'd try using explicit source elements within the <video> tag and declare the type as well (as in the W3Schhols example - http://www.w3schools.com/html5/att_video_controls.asp

Comment: I need it to play in the webpage.  Will VLC allow that?  I tried using  the W3Schools way as well and it did not play.

Comment: I updated the code to look exactly like W3Schools code.  I tested on IPad and nexus 7 and play.  The APple shows the play button with the play crossed out the Nexus shows a play button.  When I press it nothing happens.  I tested the site on a PC and the video shows up just fine and plays perfectly.  I am at a complete loss as to what the issue might be.

Comment: Can you post your actual page with link to the video itself. may be a format issue that's stopping it playing on the device (that's why I was curious to know what happened in VLC or similar)